# How to replace a variable with nothing if certain conditions are met using a if statement (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a completing the square calculator. I replicated some of the lengthy code to show where im getting my issue:

```
a=1 
if (a == 1):
print ()
```

`print ("bcdf" + str(a))`

Output: bcdf1

In this case, I want it to output bcdf

I genuinely looked all over the place trying to find an answer to this.

Comment: What do you want to do? I don't understand

Comment: Is the value of a suppose to affect the print statement? If not then why not just print('bcdf') instead of adding str(a) to the print statement? It will give you the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly the problem, but probably this is the solution you're searching for:

```
a = 1
if (a == 1):
    print("bcdf")
else:
    print("bcdf" + str(a))
```

You can find more information regarding *if..else* statements in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `a` is a number you could set it to `None` to reset its value. Also, if you are using Python>3.6 you have [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to print what you want nicely in one line:

```
a = 1
if a == 1:
    a = None
print(f"bcdf{a if a is not None else ''}")
```

This says to evaluate to an empty string if `a` is `None`.

If you do not have f-strings you can do it the old way with `format`, it does exactly the same thing:

```
a = 1
if a == 1:
    a = None
print("bcdf{}".format(a if a is not None else ""))
```